# A Shell Script to simulate the wc command with its options?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

we have to write a ***shell script*** program , which works similar to `wc` command.
receives `-l`, `-c` and `-w` as its options.

Shell scripting syntax aside; ***MY QUESTION*** is that can we simulate logic of `wc -c` or `wc -l` or `wc -w` using `sed` or `grep` or `anything else`  ; *if yes* ***then how?***

**IMP: Don't use `wc` in script**

Comment: with sed: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#wc-_002dc ... see it at your own risk

Comment: Thank you @Sundeep

Comment: Can you also explain the things that are written there ? @Sundeep

Comment: nope, I don't know about `sed` enough to understand those scripts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single `awk` command that you can parameterize by setting the appropriate `-v` variables to `0`:

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v l=1 -v w=1 -v c=1 '
      { wc+=NF; cc+=1+length($0) }
  END { printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", l ? NR : "", w ? wc: "", c ? cc : ""}
' file
```

Note:

- For simplicity, you always get 3 `\t`-separated output fields, with fields whose output wasn't requested empty; it wouldn't be hard to modify this to emulate `wc`'s output behavior, however.
- As explained in [choroba's `grep` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43940454/45375), you must prepend `LC_ALL=C`  to `awk ...`, if you really want to count *bytes* (`-c`) rather than (potentially multi-byte) *characters* (`-m`).

  - To count *characters* (the equivalent of `wc -m`), remove `LC_ALL=C`  above.
    *Caveat*: This won't work BSD `awk`, as also found on macOS, unfortunately, because it not Unicode-aware and *always* counts the number of *bytes* (try `awk '{print length($0)}' <<<ü`).
- `wc -l` strictly counts the number of `\n` characters, so it doesn't count an *incomplete* line - one missing a trailing `\n` - at the end of its input; the above `awk` command, by contrast, does count that line (and an implied trailing newline in the byte/character count).
- How it works:

  - `awk`'s `NF` variables contains the number of fields on each input line, where the line is broken into fields by arbitrary runs of whitespace by default; in other words: by default, fields are words.
  - `$0` is the input line at hand, whose `length()` tells you the number of characters / bytes, with `1` added to account for the `\n` character at the end of the line.
  - Note how variables `wc` and `cc` need to initialization, because `awk` implicitly treats empty/undefined variables as `0` in a numeric context (such as with compound operator `+=`).
  - `NR` contains the current, 1-based line number, which in the `END` block is equal to the total number of input lines.

Comment: Will `length()` work correctly on a unicode file? UTF-8 is 3 bytes per character and UTF-16LE is two bytes per character.

Comment: @JNevill: GNU Awk and Mawk handle UTF-8 encoding correctly (btw, UTF-8 is a _variable_ encoding with each character occupying between 1 (in the ASCII range) and 4 bytes), BSD/macOS Awk, sadly, does not (I've added a note). No standard utility can handle UTF-16 encoding, you'd need `iconv` to convert that to the active locale's encoding, which is virtually always UTF-8 these days.

Comment: @mklement0 That is awesome. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

`-l`:

```
awk 'END{print NR}' inFile
```

`-w`:

```
awk '{words+=NF}END{print words}' inFile
```

`-c`:

```
ls -l inFile | awk '{print $5}'
```

Comment: `ls -l` is ugly and does not work on all locales, better `stat -c "%s"`. But even better would be an `awk` solution which also works like your other solutions for multiple files and for pipes.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use `grep`, simulating the line count is easy: just count how many times something that matches always happens:

```
grep -c '^' filename
```

This should output the same as `wc -l` (but it might report one more line if the file doesn't end in a newline).

To get the number of words, you can use the following pipeline:

```
grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+' filename | grep -c '^'
```

You need `grep` that supports the `-o` option which prints each matching string to a line of its own. The expression matches all non-space sequences, and piping them into what we used in the previous case just counts them.

To get the number of characters (`wc -c`), you can use

```
LC_ALL=C grep -o . filename | grep -c '^'
```

Setting LC_ALL is needed if your locale supports UTF-8, otherwise you'd count `wc -m`. You need to add the number of newlines to the output number, so

```
echo $(( $( grep -c '^' filename ) 
         + $( LC_ALL=C grep -o . filename | grep -c '^' ) ))
```

Comment: wc -l emulation is wrong. It must not count the last line if it does not end with '\n'.

Comment: @rudimeier: It's mentioned in the answer. The fix is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Sorry I haven't read this. But I think this is a major important feature so shouldn't be missing.  Thinks have to sum-up, `wc -l a b` has to be the same like `wc -l a` + `wc -l b`